# We are having Merge Problems using Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 and Team Foundation 2013 RTM

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We are having Merge (Auto-merge) Problems using Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 and Team Foundation 2013 RTM.

My question is, is this to do with Visual Studio or TFS? We are on the latest Visual Studio at the moment, but not TFS.

Could possibly upgrading TFS potentially fix these problems? How would I find out if any known merge problems have been fixed?

Tried googling but struggled to find out this info.

Thanks

Comment: "We are having Merge Problems" doesn't give us any indication of what the problem actually is.

Comment: Well I'm not asking for an exact solution am I. Can you not just help me with my enquiries. Basically if I'm having problems, is it worth upgrading TFS? If I knew the exact problem I wouldn't be on here would I.

Comment: Sometimes when somebody has changed something in a project (i.e. adding a file), when they get the latest version (which also contains an update to that project), it goes wrong and loses the changes from the latest version. I could turn auto-merge off, but then that becomes a pain all the time.

But that's irrelevant to my question. What is actually responsible for the merging? TFS or Visual Studio? Or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would always recommend that you take the updates for TFS as they become available. If you are worried, then wait a week and then upgrade.

You should be on TFS 2013.3 as I write and 2013.4 is just around the problem. I have seen no reported "merge issues" with 2013.3, but also none with 2013.

If you don't want to update that often then I would recommend migrating to http://tfs.visualstudio.com and have MSFT do your updates for you.

Comment: Well it's just a big of a pain to upgrade TFS so basically I'm asking is it actually responsible for doing the merging or is Visual Studio?? Hence possibly helping solve our problems.

TFS online might be good, but we have a few developers, so would require buying some extra licences, and not sure of the bandwidth issues if it is hosted.

Comment: Finally updating soon.